# Copy Access table with primary keys

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc

Using C#, ODBC and the Jet 4.0 engine to work with an (old) Access database. The task requires that I do not use DAO.

The Microsoft Jet 4.0 database engine unfortunately does not support the "RENAME" keyword. All of the following throw an exception:

- RENAME TABLE old_name TO new_name;
- RENAME old_name TO new_name;
- ALTER TABLE old_name RENAME TO new_name;

But the following syntax does work:

```
SELECT * INTO new_name FROM old_name;
```

The problem is that the primary keys are not copied.

Is there a way to create a copy of a table, and in the copy preserve which fields are primary keys?

Comment: Eh... _The task requires that I do not use DAO_, why? DAO is shipped with the Access database engine so if you can make ODBC connections you generally can use DAO, and Access has limited DDL support, for many operations you need DAO.

Comment: Thanks @ErikA. That may well turn out to be an poor requirement! Our goal is create a generic interface that allows us to support both Access and other database types like MySQL. The senior developer here has set the requirement that we do NOT use DAO at all. So I'm trying to do this in raw SQL and the ODBC driver, if at all possible. I can do almost everything now in raw SQL using ODBC. If this particularly task *really* is impossible without DAO, that would be very valuable to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ODBC, you can get/grab the indexes. Most of the time, the PK column has a index called Primary key. This is not 100% guaranteed.

So, this would work "most" of the time:

eg:

```
Sub Test22()

    Using con As New OdbcConnection(My.Settings.Test44ODBC2)
        '            Using cmdSQL As New OdbcCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * From PKTEST", con)

        con.Open()

        Dim schemaTable As New DataTable
        schemaTable = con.GetSchema("Indexes", New String() {Nothing, Nothing, "PKTEST"})
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = schemaTable

    End Using

 End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

However, a user could have created the index and given it a different name.

So, for example, I can go into the above table, and re-name Primary key to anything I want - say this:

[image]

So, not really great.

However, while the application and "most" of your code could stick to ODBC?

If you use oleDB, then you CAN WITH 100% reliability get the PK, and you not had to reference DAO.

So, while the above shows we re-named the PK with "zoo" on the end, this oleDB code will STILL return the PK column like this:

```
Sub GetoleDBGetKey()

    Using con As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.TESTAce)
        Using cmdSQL As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * from PKTEST", con)

            con.Open()
            Dim schemaTable As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Primary_Keys,
                            New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, "PKTEST"})

            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = schemaTable
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

[image]

So, oleDB will work 100%.

The ODBC snip above? Well, we would have to assume "PrimaryKey", and this is not really a requirement (that it is/was named "PrimaryKey")

So, you could consider oleDB.

I not dug really deep, but I don't think ODBC can get the PK with reliability.

You could play with the odbc getSchema I have above. There are some code snips that suggests that you open  connection, open a reader, and use getschema of the data reader, and that DOES work - but I don't have a working example (or even know if this can work - but there is some suggesting that this can/does work).

Comment: This can be adapted to my needs, thanks! I've tested `OdbcConnection::GetSchema`. In the tables I'm looking at, all the primary keys are still named "PrimaryKey", so ODBC will work. But thanks for the comment that this is not guaranteed if the index has been renamed...noted! Have also tested `OleDbConnection::GetOleDbSchemaTable` and this works exactly as suggested.

Comment: As noted, some have suggested that getSchema against a odbc reader can work, but I not gone beyond getting indexes. There is a primary key flag in schema for odbc, but unfortantly it is not set. Primary key is probably ok, but as noted, this is a assumption that not 100%. Also, in that first code snip, there was no need to create a command object - that was just a cut + paste of some code I had.